# DalekJS - ForLoop inside a test

Tags: javascript, for-loop, browser-automation, dalekjs, end-to-end

I'm just experimenting with DalekJS, and I'm trying to get a Forloop to run... but the terminal gives me a... ERROR: Error: socket hang up... I just want to know the proper syntax for loops in DalekJS... any example would be awesome.

```
module.exports = {
   'lets test some functions': function (test) {
    test.open('https://instagram.com')

        for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        .wait(5000)
        }
   }
};
```

whenever I run this test the terminal returns an Error...
example ERROR: Error: socket hang up

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid JavaScript. Looks like your `.wait(5000)` should be `test.wait(5000)`

Comment: Does the error code contain the text: `Exterminate` ? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem - worked for me when I added "test" to actions inside and after the loop; i.e., test.wait() and test.done()

Comment: @MichaelYee Can you post what the correct solution looks like to the benefit of others?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [execute method](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-execute) to call custom JavaScript

```
module.exports = {
   'lets test some functions': function (test) {
    test.open('https://instagram.com')
        .execute(function(){
            for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
              test.wait(5000);
            }
        })
        .done();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work as:

```
module.exports = {
   'lets test some functions': function (test) {
    test.open('https://instagram.com')
            for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
              test.wait(5000);
            }
        test.done();
   }
};
```

Note: no execute necessary, but '**test**' needs to be appended to .wait() and .done()